# Semisimplicity conjecture

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, motives, algebraic-cycles

In this short [note](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.04489.pdf) Ben Moonen proves that over fields of characteristic zero that are of finite type over their prime field, the Tate conjecture about surjectivity of cycle maps implies the semi-simplicity of the Galois action on cohomology, the so called "semi-simplicity conjecture".

Is this implication known in char $p>0$?

Comment: Given how recent the paper is, and the fact that there is no mention of such a result in positive characteristic, I would say almost certainly no.

Comment: Of course, one easy alternative to asking everyone would be to ask Moonen!